# select rows in between period bounds and put them into an array | python | pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, loops, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, the first one `df` like this

```
date_time             value     member
2013-10-09 09:00:00  664639  Jerome
2013-10-09 09:05:00  197290  Hence
2013-10-09 09:10:00  470186  Ann
2013-10-09 09:15:00  181314  Mikka
2013-10-09 09:20:00  969427  Cristy
2013-10-09 09:25:00  261473  James
2013-10-09 09:30:00  003698  Oliver
```

and the second dataframe `bounds` where I have the bounds like :

```
   date_start            date_end
2013-10-09 09:19:00         2013-10-09 09:25:00
2013-10-09 09:25:00         2013-10-09 09:40:00
```

so I need to select from first table the rows between date_start and date_end, and put every selection into the array.
I tried following code:

```
  def create_interval():
        intervals=[]
        for i in range(1,len(bounds)):
            for j in range(1, len(df)):
                mask[i] = df[(df['date'][j] > bounds.date_start[i]) & (df['date'][j] < bounds.date_end[i])]
                df_interval[i]=df.loc[mask[i]]
                intervals.append(df_interval.values)
            return intervals
```

I get this error:

```
  pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3824)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3704)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12280)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12231)()

KeyError: False
```

I suppose that a problem is with indexes but I'm not sure. Maybe there is a problem with iterating over the rows,or with selecting the intervals of date_time, or with stocking the selecting values in array

I'm a beginner in python so any help will be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally the method that works for me is following:

```
 mask = (df['date_time'] > start_date) & (df['date_time'] < end_date)
```

so I mix some transformations that @Fabio proposed me with the method above, and it created 
the array I needed. I suppose the method `between_time` doesn't work for dates, and only for times, so it couldn't recognize date-time type, and threw the error `TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex` but let me know if I'm wrong about it!
so my final function that works looks like:

```
def create_interval():
    intervales=[]
    for index, row in bounds.iterrows():
        s = row['date_start']
        e = row['date_end']
        mask = (df['date_time'] > s) & (df['date_time'] < e)
        df_interval=df.loc[mask]
        intervales.append(df_interval.values)
    return intervales
```

thanks a lot @Fabio for his participation and help

Answer (score 1):

I would pass the `date_time` column of `df` as a date and set it as index with:

```
df = df.set_index(['date_time'])
```

Then I'd apply the `between_time` pandas function to filter the dataframe by start and end date given by the `bounds` dataframe:

```
for index,row in bounds.iterrows():

     s = row['date_start']
     e = row['date_end']
     d = df.between_time(s,e)
```

This returns (for each row of `bounds`):

```
                      value  member
date_time                          
2013-10-09 09:20:00  969427  Cristy
2013-10-09 09:25:00  261473   James

                      value  member
date_time                          
2013-10-09 09:25:00  261473   James
2013-10-09 09:30:00    3698  Oliver
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT:
If you need to put the results in an array you can just call:

```
d.values
```

which returns (for the second row selection):

```
[[261473 'James']
 [3698 'Oliver']]
```

Comment: @fuzzzy_09 you have to set the 'date_time' column as index with `df = df.set_index(['date_time'])`, otherwise the between_time method does not work.

Comment: as I mentioned it in my comment before, I made it with this line ```f=df.set_index(['date_time'])``` but it doesn't work!

Comment: For me it works, how do you import the dataframe? I read it through a .csv file with the option parse_dates as `df = pd.read_csv('youfile.csv',parse_dates=['date_time'])`or you can set it as datetime with `df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])`.

Comment: the same import for me! but let's see, I loop over the rows in ```bounds``` dataframe, so I suppose there are some probleme with it's index?

Comment: I don't know, I've imported bounds as a .csv file with no option with `bounds = pd.read_csv('bounds.csv')`. There is something wrong in your code, it should be s = row['date_start'] not s = bounds['date_start'], the same for the end time.

Comment: actually I create the dataframe ```bounds``` from dataframe ```df``` with some external indicators, but I don't think that it could influence smth! I changed ```s = bounds['date_start']``` for ```s = row['date_start']``` but it still throws the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91855/discussion-between-fuzzzy-09-and-fabio).